# How can I get contents in floating div to wrap on browser resize but not line break

Tags: css, css-float

I have 2 divs that needs to be displayed next to each other. The first div has just a number and the other is a link. When the browser (Firefox and chrome) is resized it places the 2nd div on a new line then wraps the text. I want the text of the 2nd div to wrap inline with the 1st.

here is my code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>

           .row {    
                    border: 1px solid yellow;
                    width: 100%;
                    overflow: auto; 
                }

          .cell {
                    float:left;    
                    border: 1px solid red;  
                }

        </style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="cell">
        <a>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
        This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
        This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
        This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get in firefox but this is an not what I want
[image]

This is what I get In IE which is what I want.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using `display:table-cell` instead of floats:

```
.row {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmNgh/).

Comment: Hi this works for Firefox and not IE 8. I need it to work of Firefox IE 8 and chrome.

Comment: IE8 supports table-cell allright, see [here](http://www.thebackoffice.be/test.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to float two block elements without giving them widths.
A div is a block element (default = display: block;). That means that it will always stretch to width: 100% unless you specify its width.
When trying to float two elements that are each width: 100%; they can't remain on the same line/row. (200% > 100% max);